# Code Execution Has Been Interrupted with Save Prevention Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I've used a similar method to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30806893/4163002) to force users to use a certain button to save.
I have the following:

### public variable

```
Dim MacroSave As Boolean
```

### button event

```
Sub RealSave_Click()
MacroSave = True
ThisWorkbook.Save
MacroSave = False
End Sub
```

### save catcher

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not MacroSave Then
    Cancel = True 'Cancels any request to save the file
    MsgBox "Workbook not saved."
    Else
    Ret = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save?", vbCritical Or vbYesNo, "Save File?")
        If Ret = vbNo Then Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

### sadness

The above code worked perfectly for some amount of time, but now it's telling me `Code execution has been interrupted` at `MacroSave = False`. If I hit `Continue` on the error pop-up, the file has saved fine. I can't see anything not working properly; it's just this pesky pop-up.

### I tried

- adding `DoEvents` before `MacroSave = False` (and after
  `ThisWorkbook.Save`), but the code was interrupted on `DoEvents`.
- moving that line to the "*save catcher*", but the same error 
  came up on the `End Sub` for the button event.
- `On Error Resume Next`, which does not eliminate this issue.

#### What am I doing wrong and how can I eliminate this?

Comment: I'm wondering if you have some sort of race condition because the workbook is taking time to save and so you move to the last line of `RealSave_Click` before the `Workbook_BeforeSave` finishes. What if you declare `MacroSave = false` where it is dimensioned and eliminate `MacroSave = false` in `RealSave_Click`?

Comment: @MattCremeens I agree; that definitely seems like the case. A couple problems with your suggestion: (1) I've moved around the `MacroSave = False`, but the code is interrupted on the `End Sub` of `RealSave_Click()`. (2) I have to reset `MacroSave` to False at some point. (3) I believe assigning a value to `MacroSave` outside of a sub or function would be invalid.

Comment: Since you made it public, you could declare it in a workbook open event.

Comment: I am assuming up to you have something like `Option Explicit Dim MacroSave as Boolean`.

Comment: @MattCremeens Oh, ok; I apologize. I would like to be able to potentially save multiple times while it's open, though...

Comment: I do not have `Option Explicit`, but I have the rest, yes.

Comment: Did you use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code where you declared `MacroSave`?

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` and I think it may work for you.

Comment: @MattCremeens Unfortunately not. :/ Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other suggestions are great, but...it boils down to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5823507/4163002):

1. Press "Debug" button in the popup.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause|Break</kbd> twice.
3. Hit the play button to continue.
4. Save the file after completion.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

Regular module:

```
Option Explicit

Public MacroSave As Boolean

Sub RealSave_Click()

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, _
             "Save File?") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo haveError
    MacroSave = True
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    MsgBox "Saved!"

haveError:
    MacroSave = False

End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook module:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not MacroSave Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Workbook not saved: please use the 'Save changes'" & _
               " button to save this workbook"
    End If
End Sub
```